# How to Less cardinality and cost of my sql

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]
Above is result i just want to low cardinality cost just.
I have **Multiple subquery** i want to less **cardinality cost** what should i do. i have tried to do it with with clause but it will not set according with my requirements query execute fine but cardinality and cost is much higher that's why i want to split cardinality

```
select distinct
C.CLASS_ID,
C.TEACHER_ID,

C.SHIFT_ID,
C.BRANCH_ID,
T.TEACHER_NAME,
ns.nazim_id,
c.class_uid,
(Select count(*) AS total_class from student where upper(class_id)=upper(C.CLASS_ID) and is_active_flg='Y'
and status='STUDYING'
and upper(class_days) like '%'||TO_CHAR(to_date(:P28_DATE),'DY')||'%') as Total_Students,

(select count(*) from student
where class_id=C.CLASS_ID and is_active_flg='Y') as Active_Students,


(select count(*) from student
where class_id=C.CLASS_ID and is_active_flg='N') as InActive_Students,

(Select count(*) as Marked from student_class_attend where upper(class_id)=C.CLASS_ID
and attend_date =:P28_DATE) as Attend_Marked,

(select count(*)
from student
where class_id=C.CLASS_ID and is_active_flg='Y' and gr_number not in (select gr_number from student_class_attend where attend_date=:P28_DATE)
) as Attend_UnMarked,

(select count(*) from student_class_attend
where class_id=C.CLASS_ID and attend_date=:P28_DATE and submit_flg='Y') as attend_submitted,

(select count(*) from student_class_attend
where class_id=C.CLASS_ID and attend_date=:P28_DATE and submit_flg='N') as attend_pending


--qc.unconfirmed
from CLASS C
--join class_time ct on c.class_uid = ct.class_uid
LEFT JOIN student_class_attend SC ON sc.class_id=c.class_id
join nazim_shift ns on decode(:V_GENDER,'BOTH',c.gender,ns.gender) = c.gender
and instr(ns.department_id||':',c.department_id||':')>0
and instr(ns.branch_id||':',c.branch_id||':')>0
and instr(ns.shift_id||':',c.shift_id||':')>0
and ns.nazim_login_id = lower(trim(:APP_USER))
--join nazim_shift_time nst on ns.nazim_shift_uid = nst.nazim_shift_uid
--and nst.class_time=ct.class_time
left join TEACHER T ON C.TEACHER_ID = T.TEACHER_ID and t.active_flg = 'Y'
where c.active_flg = 'Y'
order by c.class_id
;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query does would all help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i dont want any desire result this query return 12-15 values class id and their student details this works fine i just want to less cardinality cost

Comment: It have many subqueries which take enough cardinality cost i want to minimize it

Comment: replace the correlated sub queries with window functions and see if they perform better.

Comment: @ Gabriel Durac bro Any  Refrence For Help.?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already join with student_class_attend. You could replace the correlated subqueries for Attend_Marked and attend_submitted with window functions.

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN sc.attend_date =:P28_DATE THEN 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY sc.CLASS_ID)as Attend_Marked,
,SUM(CASE WHEN sc.attend_date=:P28_DATE and sc.submit_flg='Y' THEN 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY sc.CLASS_ID) as attend_submitted,
```

You can also join with student and do similiar for the other subqueries.
You can read about analytical function [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions)

Comment: if these two work and you still need help I can expand on the answer. But I need to know the relationship cardinality between the tables involved.

Comment: And for Student subquery.?

Comment: i took advantage of the fact you were joining with `student_class_attend`, you could do it in a similar fashion after joining with `student`. I am not familiar with your data, so I do not know how this will affect the query and how you will need to make your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any sample data or the explain plan to really tell you for sure. However, there are a few things you can do anyhow to improve on this.
You can rewrite your query using a join instead of a subquery for Active_Students and InActive_Students as this runs for each row. You can use CASE and group by clauses for this. Similarly, for the other fields, you should follow this as well, unless there is a specific reason you are not doing this.

Moreover, I see you are using a lot of functions in your join conditions, normally it is a good practice to put that in the where clause.